# Proper way to sync setInterval and transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

**Problem statement**

To move the square along the perimeter of the viewport on click of the button as can be seen in the example:

https://codepen.io/vineetrok/pen/XRowdB

**What do I need?**

I'm using this code in combination with the `transition` property in the CSS. I think combination of `transition` and `setInterval()` is causing a delay. Is there a better and efficient method to accomplish this only using javascript?

Following is my code:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box" style="left:0;top:0"></div>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="init()">Start!</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

**JS**

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".box");
var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
var dimension = elem.clientWidth;
var deltaX = viewportWidth - dimension;
var deltaY = viewportHeight - dimension;

function move(x,y){
  if(x <=0 && y==0){
    elem.style.left=(deltaX)+"px";
  }
  else if(x==(deltaX) && y==0){
    elem.style.top=(deltaY)+"px";
  }
  else if(x==(deltaX) && y==(deltaY)){
    elem.style.left="0px";
  }
  else if(x==0 && y==(deltaY)){
    elem.style.top="0px";
  }

}

function getCoordinates(elem){
  return {
    x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
  }
}

var init = function(){
  var clearTimer = 1;
  var startTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
    move(getCoordinates(elem).x,getCoordinates(elem).y )
    }, 1000);
      clearTimer++;
      if(clearTimer>=4){
        clearInterval(startTimer);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generally say that using both css and javascript to manage a transition is going to cause trouble.  Part of the problem is that javascript timers aren't very precise.  If you set a timer for 1 second it doesn't actually sleep for exactly one second.  The exact amount of time it sleeps can vary depending on how busy the CPU is, what the user is doing, etc.  It is very easy for the javascript timer to take longer than the CSS animation.

Since you are using jQuery I would use the jQuery.animate function to run things.  It has a callback function that is invoked when the animation completes, and you can use that to execute the next step of the animation without any timers at all.  That will make sure there aren't any delays.  It should also be *fairly* performant.  CSS animations are usually the slowest in terms of computer performance, so I expect jQuery.anmiate to probably be a bit better.  There are other libraries out there designed for high performance animations, but unless performance actually becomes a problem, I wouldn't worry about it.  Right now your issue is likely the imprecise timing of the timeout method, and not any performance issues.

Comment: I disagree. CSS animations are hardware accelerated, and will always be much lighter and faster than JS-computed animations, which are handled by the CPU.

Comment: It is more complicated than that (and also more complicated than my quick summary).  Some CSS transitions can use hardware acceleration, but not all do, and the ones that don't are frequently slower than javascript.  But it depends on a large number of factors.  Either way, it is complicated enough that unless you know that performance is an issue, it is best to select the solution that best solves your problem and not worry about performance issues.  Here is a quick read: https://greensock.com/css-performance  Also https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions

Comment: @ConorMancone I agree that using both JS and CSS to manage transition causes trouble. I get different timings on every run. Also, I know the jquery solution for this. But i'm looking for a JS only solution here. I'm trying to eliminate any CSS transitions too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that note in your OP about javascript only.  I don't think there is an answer out-of-the-box.  That being said, there really is no reason why you can't make your own animate function in pure javascript to accomplish what I outlined.  There is one potential answer on that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609037/can-someone-give-me-a-standalone-code-of-the-jquery-animation-functions  It still uses timers but the difference is that you can start the next step when the current step finishes: lack of ability to do that is what causes the css/js issue.

Comment: (I may have time to put together a demo later, but can't right now)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at it (I developed something from scratch instead of reusing your code) :

```js
let box=document.getElementById("box"),
 isLeft = false,
 isTop = false

const toggleLeft = () => {
  box.style.left = (isLeft=!isLeft) ? "calc( 100% - 50px )" : "0";
  setTimeout(toggleTop, 2000);
}

const toggleTop = () => {
  box.style.top = (isTop=!isTop) ? "calc( 100% - 50px )" : "0";
  setTimeout(toggleLeft, 2000);
}

setTimeout(toggleLeft, 1000)
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

And a more condensed and recursive version :

```js
let box=document.getElementById("box"),
 is = { left : false, top : false }

const toggle = what => {
  box.style[what] = (is[what]=!is[what]) ? "calc( 100% - 50px )" : "0";
  setTimeout(()=>toggle(what==="left"?"top":"left"), 2000);
}

setTimeout(()=>toggle("left"), 100)
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```