# Animate element using Javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, animation

How can I animate an element with Javascript vanilla?
Similar with jquery. Example:

```
$( "button.continue" ).animate({left: "100px", top: "200px"}, 5000);
```

Where we pass the attribute, the desired value and the time.

In my case I need the left and top position to animate and slide.

**Solution**

I've done as @IceMetalPunk sugested and added the animation by css only when I need to animate.

```js
document.getElementById("animate").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let e = document.getElementById('elementToAnimate');

  e.classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(()=> e.classList.remove("animate"), 500);

  e.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 'px';
  e.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 'px';
});

document.getElementById("dontAnimate").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let e = document.getElementById('elementToAnimate');

  e.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 'px';
  e.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 'px';
});
```

```css
#elementToAnimate {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#elementToAnimate.animate {
  transition: left 500ms ease-in-out, top 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="elementToAnimate"></div>

<button id="animate">Animate</button>
<button id="dontAnimate">Dont Animate</button>
```

Comment: Why not do it with CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609037/can-someone-give-me-a-standalone-code-of-the-jquery-animation-functions

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't want to animate every time, and if I insert a `transition` in the element it will animate every time it changes its `left`and `top` position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using CSS transitions. In CSS, do something like this:

```
button.continue {
  transition: 5s;
}
```

Then in JS, you can just set the left/top values:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.continue').forEach(button => {
  button.style.left = '100px';
  button.style.top = '200px';
});
```

Comment: I don't want to animate every time, and if I insert a `transition` in the element it will animate every time it changes its `left`and `top` position

Comment: In that case, I recommend toggling an "animate" class on and off when you want to animate it. That class would only have the `transition` property, so when it's toggled on, properties will animate, and when it's toggled off, they won't.

Answer (score 4):

Tested in Firefox.

```
document
   .querySelector(".text.thank-you")
   .animate({ opacity: [0, 1] }, { duration: 5000, iterations: 1, easing: "ease-out" })
   .onfinish = (e) => {
        e.target.effect.target.style.opacity = 1;
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API). Its an experimental feature so [Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_animation) (mainly Safari) might be an issue for you. Otherwise you can do it the way others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **WebComponents**, you can perform any kind of animation using only **VanillaJS**, there are predefined animations like *Animate.css* but you can create custom animations by using *keyFrames*:

```html
<!-- Add Web Animations Polyfill :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@proyecto26/animatable-component@1.0.0/dist/animatable-component/animatable-component.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@proyecto26/animatable-component@1.0.0/dist/animatable-component/animatable-component.js"></script>

<animatable-component
  autoplay
  easing="ease-in-out"
  duration="1200"
  delay="300"
  animation="heartBeat"
  iterations="Infinity"
  style="display: flex;align-self: center;"
>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</animatable-component>
```

For more details check here: https://github.com/proyecto26/animatable-component