# How to Convert jquery to javascript i am a beginner

Tags: html

This is part of my HTML code

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

I was told not to use jquery at school.
so I want to convert this jquery to javascript and use it What should i do?

Comment: You're calling three different jQuery functions there. What, specific, problem are you having rewriting any of them without jQuery? Your question gives the impression that you've done [absolutely no research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Why have you formatted your code as two separate live demos, one with HTML, one with JavaScript, and without loading the jQuery library the JS depends on?

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275840/animate-element-using-javascript-vanilla

Comment: fwiw, jquery is a javascript library so jquery IS javascript.

Comment: Thank you teachers for your good opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Do it yourself using the following steps:

1. Change the `$()`s to `document.querySelector()`s.
   for example:

```js
$('.message a').click(function() {
```

should be

```js
document.querySelector('.message a').onclick = function() {
```

2. Make a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) for what `animation()` function did.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code

```
document.querySelector('.message a').click(function(){
   document.querySelector('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: That won't work. DOM `click` doesn't do what jQuery `click` does and there is no `animate` method on the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin Could you please check this Web API documentation, I think we have animate method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected. There *is* an `animate` method … but it isn't the same as jQuery's and takes different arguments so you're still using it wrong.